# Multiple Wiener-Ito integral distribution

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, integration, stochastic-calculus, simulation

Distribution of standard Ito integral is well known: $$I_1(f) = \int_0^T f(t)dB(t) \sim \mathcal{N}\bigg(0, \int_0^T f^2(t)dt\bigg).$$
Is it possible to find the distribution of multiple Wiener-Ito integral: $$I_n(f) = \int_{[0,T]^n} f(t_1, \dots, t_n) dB(t_1) \cdots dB(t_n)$$

Comment: I don't know of a closed form expression, but there are certainly lots of results about such distributions.  You might like to look up "Wiener chaos".

Answer (score 1):

Below some references regarding distributional properties of Wiener chaoses

- The book, Gaussian Hilbert spaces, by S. Janson, is a standard reference to start with. In particular, you might want to read Chapters 2, 5 and 6. Chapter 6 contains general tail bound.
- For precise moment and tails estimates, you can have a look at this: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1171377444.
- Regarding absolute continuity of the laws, you might want to check these: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250522278 and https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195517581
- Regarding anti-concentration, Theorem 8 of http://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/journals/items/mrl/content/vols/0008/0003/a001/ can help.
- Finally, there are many open questions when the order of the multiple Wiener-Itô integral is greater than 3.